# Dropdown menu appears behind surrounding parent element

Tags: css, z-index

Trying to add an AddEvent button, which has a dropdown. It does however not show outside of it's parent element. I've tried adding position relative to the various divs surronding the button, but to no effect. The menu has the highest z-index on the page.

Any ideas?

[Pastebin with some markup](http://pastebin.com/x1Kk5NFM). The dropdown is the first span at line 74.

[CSS for the dropdown span](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qn5yi.jpg)

[image]
[image]

Comment: give me u code. )

Comment: I'm afraid no way

Comment: It would be very helpful if you post your code. Now, I can never help as I do not know your code structure.

Comment: Need to set z-index

Comment: does not really help without the css. Issue could be related to `overflow: hidden;`, or your `z-index` element does not have `position: relative | absolute;`

Comment: @Dejan.S The span has a high z-index, and position absolute.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by setting `overflow: visible;` on the table element.

Thanks to [Dejan.S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/148601/dejan-s) for the hint.